# How to change my OneHotEncoder to prepare for changes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

So currently the way I am encoding my categorical features is like this:

```
# Import the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('weatherHistory_edited.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:, 6].values

# Encode categorical features
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 5] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,5])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features= [5])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

And this works fine, the only thing is I get the warning that categorical_features is a deprecated keyword in version 0.20 and will be removed in 0.22. You can use the ColumnTransformer instead.

So I switched the last block of code to this:

```
# Encode categorical features
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

columntransformer = ColumnTransformer([("one_hot_encoder", OneHotEncoder(), [5])], remainder= "passthrough")
X = np.array(columntransformer.fit_transform(X))
```

Now when I use this code, I don't get an error but my X array gets completely messed up and even changes to a weird tuple.

The extra weird part is that when using a different dataset, that code does seem to work. 
Example:

```
# Import the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values

# Encode categorical features
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

columntransformer = ColumnTransformer([("one_hot_encoder", OneHotEncoder(), [3])], remainder= "passthrough")
X = np.array(columntransformer.fit_transform(X))
```

In this example the X value gets the expected value.

I uploaded the example datasets to a public repo so you can recreate the problem:

https://github.com/BjornPijpops/encoding_issue

Comment: Is the `dtype` of your categorical column the same in each instance?

Comment: Yes the dtype is the same for both instances.